# Combining Path Tracing and Photon Mapping

Tags: pathtracing, implementation, photon-mapping

I'm trying to implementing the paper "[Deep Kernel Density Estimation for Photon Mapping](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/%7Ehenrik/papers/deep_photon_mapping.pdf)". One part that has me confused is when the authors describe their rendering algorithm as hybrid algorithm combining Path Tracing and Photon Mapping (with their neural network):

> Moreover, our experiments leverages an effective practical hybrid
> approach: using our method for reconstructing light-specular (LS)
> paths – the light transport paths that interact with specular surfaces
> before arriving at light sources—and low sample-count path tracing
> with learning-based denoising for all other light transport paths.
> This leverages the advantages of both MC denoising and our efficient
> photon density estimation technique.

another section:

> Combining MC denoising and deep photon mapping. We evaluate
> our deep photon density estimation by combining our method
> with MC denoising. Specifically, we apply our learning-based density
> estimation to only compute the challenging light transport effects which involve LS paths that are extremely hard to trace in PT
> and likely to introduce caustics. In addition, we use path tracing
> with relatively low sample counts to compute the remaining light
> transport paths, and use modern learning-based denoising—the Optix
> built-in denoiser based on [CKS17]—to remove the MC noise.

But there are not enough details about the way they combine them. Of course, I'm familiar with multiple importance sampling and the paper "Vertex Connection and Merging" but the way they describe it seems to be more about flipping a switch between them based on if they are rending caustics/SDS paths or not. I can't really imagine how to decide between them while rendering without MIS. But I also don't think they implemented VCM with the paper since it will severely hurt the performance which is one of the main parts of the evaluation.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks in advance!